# React Navigation losing props that are passed down

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a container connected to redux which inherits the 'global state' as props thanks to the `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` line...

The container `(Container.js)` in turn passes down the props to the Table `(Table.js)`, which receives them fine as expected.

My issue occurs when I try to make the Table a Navigation stack. Reason being I want to be able to click on each row which would navigate to the DetailPage which would be populated by the different props dependant on rows.

However when adding `StackNavigator` all my props passed down from the Container are gone and only the React Navigation ones are there (`navigation: {actions:{goBack... ETC}}`).

Note: This also happens if I `connect` the Component directly.

Below is a dummied down example of my code structure.

What am I doing wrong/How do I maintain the props passed down?

Container.js

```
class Container extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Table {...this.props} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: state.data,
    propTwo: state.propTwo
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    functionOne: () => dispatch(functionOne()),
    functionTwo: arg => dispatch(functionTwo(arg))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Market);
```

Table.js

```
const DetailPage = () => <View><Text>Just a mock page</Text></View>

class Table extends Component {
  keyExtractor = (item, index) => index;
  renderItem = (argOne, index) => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        onPress={() => this.props.navigate(argOne)}
        key={index} />
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          data={this.props.data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              onRefresh={this.props.functionTwo}
            />
          }
        />
      </View>
    ) 
  }
}
// react-navigation StackNavigator
export default Table = StackNavigator({
  Table: { screen: Table },
  DetailPage: { screen: DetailPage }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the `StackNavigator` into `Container.js`:

```
export default StackNavigator({
  Table: { screen: connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container) },
  DetailPage: { screen: DetailPage }
});
```

Also you can `connect` to `Table` directly instead of creating a `Container` wrapper class:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Table` is a `StackNavigator`, you can pass props to it using the `screenProps` prop as mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props)

> The navigator component created by StackNavigator(...) takes the following props:
>
> screenProps - Pass down extra options to child screens, for example:

The end result would be:

```
class Container extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Table screenProps={{...this.props}} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Which you can access on `Table` as `this.props.screenProps.data`